# Alternator/Battery power question

Tags: battery, alternator, power

Good Afternoon,

I have a 2014 Ford Focus SE that i use as my Work Vehicle. I work in Emergency Roadside Assistance. I have to run a laptop In the car in order to direct calls to other employees and charge a hotspot and phone. Recently i have been interested in adding an amplifier and Sub into the car as i spend 12 hours a day driving to calls. I have the laptop and chargers running through a 140amp/400amp(Peak) power converter. My father is a mechanic and has expressed some concern about adding the amp and sub into the vehicle with everything else the vehicle is running already. Im looking for any ideas that dont involve adding a second batter unless that is my absolute only way. Please assist with any positive and negative side affects of option.

Thanks, 
Devon

Comment: How many amps does your alt produce?

Comment: your car battery must be an 100AH or more battery. It should be more than enough for what you're  trying to do. let me know the power consumption of subs

Answer (score 1):

When you have your subs hooked up, have someone install a capacitor, a spare battery for your subs. Shouldn't be any extra cost. It just goes from the power to the amp.